# Swift 5.1 - Mac OS - File reading is working in playground but not working in application

Tags: swift, macos, file

Same code is working in Playgrounds as expected - answer is "File EXISTS". Exactly same code (copy - paste) placed in small ("empty") application in override func awakeFromNib() or in func applicationDidFinishLaunching() is replying "*** NO SUCH FILE ***". Have no idea what is happening.

```
import Cocoa

let path = "/users/myName/Documents/ReadAndWriteFiles/ChartData.txt"
let myString = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
var array: [String] = [String]()  
if let myTestString = myString
{
    array = myTestString.components(
        separatedBy: CharacterSet (charactersIn: ","))
    print("*** File EXISTS ***")
}
else
{
    print("*** NO SUCH FILE ***")
}
print(array)
```

Comment: It's probably because of [sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)

Comment: Rather no. All boxes in Signing & Capabilities -> App Sandbox are unchecked and File Access Type is selected as "Read Only" - have changed this to Read & Write but it has no influence. Signing Certificate is set to "Sign and Run Locally". Very strange as if something is working in Playground should be working in the application too.

Comment: Have checked it with codesign -dvvv --entitlements :- <executable-path> with result as below: 
 <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key>
 <true/>

Comment: as already mentioned your app sandbox is enabled

Comment: @ Leo & Alladinian: Well, well, well, :-) two guys are saying same :-) so must be something in it. ....security.files.user-selected.read-only is also set to "true" - so what!? Can I read the file or not!?. On the other hand have no slightest idea how to switch all these "security" off.  OK - for last over 40 years I was writing a "numerical" part of many apps - numerical methods - in the other words "mathematics". Very little  or none (closer to none) UI. To me it looks "something went wrong". Yes 52 in my nick is my birth year. Previous century. :-)

Comment: if you need access to a directory outside your app bundle if sandbox is enabled you need to present a NSSavePanel to allow the user to select the desired location/directory. If you need posterior access you can bookmark your url and use SecurtyScoped flag https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417795-bookmarkdata

Comment: Thanks Leo! That clarifies a lot.